# Xamarin ios Share Extension Crashes on try to get stream of an .mov file

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash, ios8-share-extension, .mov

We currently are workiong on an share extension (xamarin ios) for mediafiles. Every thing working fine expecpt .mov files.

Every kind of attempt to load them in an stream or get any bit of the shared .mov files failed with an app crash.

Could anyone say why or has an solution for this kind of poblem?

We tried:
NSData .AsSteam/.ToArray and foreach
File.Load
FileInfo.openRead
AVAssets

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO! Do you mean that other files will share successfully ?And you can share more code about sharing `.mov` file .

Comment: All files shred successfully except .mov files. For code i use the same code like the demo  from xamarin. to load the file if tryed every posible provider for xamarin ios.   Example: new NSData(Url you get by using NSItemProvider LoadItemAsync).AsStream();

Comment: Okey , what about the size of `.mov` file , you can have a try with a samll szie `.mov` file to check whether it works . Generally , `.mov` file stored with large size , I think it maybe the problem .

Comment: for testing purpose i used mutiple files with mutiple file sizes. the smalest file has an size of 14.5 mb

Comment: Got it. If good solution will share here later .

Comment: OK, looking forward to it.

Comment: Hi , you also can share the tried code in question , then I will check that in my local site to find the solution .